# php: using extends with a class alias

Tags: php, namespaces, extends, aliases

I have classes in two different namespaces, for example:

Controller is in \Core,
Index is in \Public

In my index.php, I have a class_alias for all of the \Core classes, so you can call them directly: `$controller = new Controller();`.  This works without issue.

My problem is when I try to extend the class.  Since Index & Controller are in different namespaces, it tries to find Controller in the \Public namespace so this doesn't work:

```
<?php
namespace Panel\Pub;

class Index extends Controller {
```

Is there any way around this so I can use the class alias in the extends function?  I know I can use \Core\Controller and it will work, but I'm trying to use aliases to make core functions more easily accessible.

**Edit: Found one workaround**
After doing some more testing, I found that using \ in front of the alias in the extend seems to work.  Not as ideal as no \ but currently the best solution results in:

```
class Index extends \Controller { }
```

Still looking for other advice on a work around or different method of extending controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using a namespace, you use the full path in your namespace

```
class Index extends \Public\Controller { }
```

`\` represents the root of your namespace.

---

Another way to do this is to use the `use` keyword

```
namespace Panel\Pub;
use \Public\Controller as Controller
class Index extends Controller { }
```

Comment: Yes, it would be \Core\Controller but I am trying to see if there is a way to use the alias I setup for Controller to avoid using the use/fully qualified method.

Comment: Yes, I know about the use method too.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to duplicate that or \Core\ across all of the scripts extending core classes.

Comment: class_alias is set in the index.  Class alias allows you to call classes by an alias, I have the alias set from \Core\Controller to Controller.  However, this alias is not available when I am trying to extend Controller, only when I'm calling the class directly.  I was looking to see if there was a way to apply the alias to the extends as well.  I know the standard methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand then. You want to extend `Controller` which is extended by `Index`?

Comment: I guess you could look at it like this.  Class_alias is set so the main script recognizes Controller, not just \Core\Controller, which is similar to the 'use as' method you provided.  The main script calls the \Public\Index class, which extends Controller.  While the main script can call just Controller, the \Public\Index cannot and must call \Core\Controller.  PHP may not have a method around this, I was looking for one.  It seems more logical to find a solution to not have to call \Core everytime, but I am making use of namespaces throughout the whole project.

Comment: There may not be a way to do it in 5.3. 5.4 introduced Traits, which also use `use`, but inside the class and it functions like a straight copy and paste. Thus you could include Controller as often as you like (assuming I have all this straight)

Comment: Well thanks for trying to help, I found a slight work around.  It recognizes the alias if I use \Controller.  That is better than \Core\Controller I suppose.  Still not as ideal as no \ but getting there.