# make class names first letter capital with regex

Tags: regex

I have multiple classes

```
class actors extends CI_Controller {
}    

class movies extends CI_Controller {
}

class producers extends CI_Controller {
}

class shows extends CI_Controller {
}
```

I want to capitalize the class name so the result is

```
class Actors extends CI_Controller {
}    

class Movies extends CI_Controller {
}

class Producers extends CI_Controller {
}

class Shows extends CI_Controller {
}
```

So i have to do find and replace with regex.

find
`class\s`

replace
`class\s`

How do i capitalize the class names?

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to do. Are you trying to execute this regex in IDE or are writing PHP code that will process PHP files and capitalize class names there?

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638319/3832970).

Comment: @p0358 I'm trying to execute in IDE

Comment: Why can't you just rename them, or is this impossible? Edit: [might be relevant...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19943995/1415724). @user892134

Comment: Use the pattern `(class\s)([a-z])` and replace with `\1\U\2`. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/eHSC5M/1).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed  Thanks got it working

Comment: Or `class\s+\K[a-z]` => `\u$0`, `\b(class\s+)([a-z])` => `$1\u$2`, etc. I linked to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37563098/3832970) that will help you master these kinds of replacements.